# How big does ground need to be? Step down from 5v10a to 1.2V 50a, do I need a 50 amp ground?

Tags: voltage-regulator, ground, amperage, cpu, computers

I'm just a layman. I was just thinking about CPUs in computers. They run at about 1, 1.5 volts or there about, sometimes even lower. Desktop cpus can take 90 watts, some 120 watts. That's close to 100 amps at 1 volt. How can they return 100 amps to ground? Does the voltage regulator up convert ground somehow so that 100 amps doesn't go back through the mains circuit?

What if you tied the ground of a voltage regulator to the same ground as a 1 volt 100 amp circuit? So you have 5 volts 10 amps and 1 volts 100 amps returning via the same ground. How does ground not blow up?

Comment: Ground is ground. Consider the water analogy of pouring bucket of water from 10 metre and 100 metre , the ground still stays same(at same level)

Comment: The CPUs draw their power from your house at 110V, so they only draw an amp using your numbers.

Comment: I don't think you have the right view of ground. I don't think you can blow up ground unless you split an atom.

Answer (score 2):

> Desktop cpus can take 90 watts, some 120 watts. That's close to 100
>   amps at 1 volt. How can they return 100 amps to ground? Does the
>   voltage regulator up convert ground somehow so that 100 amps doesn't
>   go back through the mains circuit?

In a circuit the current must return back to the source, so the current returns back to the power supply of the computer. This means that the return current pathway must be low resistance with multiple grounds on the ATX cable and a large grounding plane with copper. The current back to the computer power supply is the amount that the DC to DC converter uses, and there are several voltages to choose from like 12V, 5V and 3.3V that can be stepped down by a DC to DC converter. There are also multiple converters.

The return current to the supply is also calculated at the DC/DC converter, so if you have a 12V DC/DC converter that steps down to 1V and your using 90W only 7.5A would be returned to the ATX supply on the ground, not 90A. For the cables, you would need to keep them low impedance but not that much. Most power supplies use 22ga to 16ga wire, this keeps the resistance in the 10mΩ's range. If you only had one 18ga wire that was 2ft long, that would be 12mΩ. 100Amps would be P=I^2*R so 7.5^2*0.012=0.675W, however, there are more cables, some ATX supplies have more than 10 grounds so the resistance would be 10 times lower, 7.5^2*0.0012=0.0675W dissipated in the cables.

> What if you tied the ground of a voltage regulator to the same ground
>   as a 1 volt 100 amp circuit? So you have 5 volts 10 amps and 1 volts
>   100 amps returning via the same ground. How does ground not blow up?

The ground does not 'blow up' because the resistance is kept low, there are multiple converters. On a typical ATX board, you will notice multiple DC DC converters. Even with a large return current from the processor, with multiple converters, the return current will be paralleled between the converters. In the simplistic case of your 100A 1V example, with 16 converters each would only get 6.25A.

[image]
https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/voltage_regulator_module

If you do need to run amps of current, the cross sectional area of the conductor needs to be increased to reduce heating. A copper trace with 0.5oz copper and 100mil wide will only heat to 40C above ambient with almost 6A of current through it. Ground planes are much larger/wider than that.

Answer (score 0):

A *circuit* has to have the same current flowing in as out.

On the low voltage high current side of a DC-DC converter the ground path will typically be as large (actually typically larger) as the power one.  Generally both are implemeneted as `power planes` in the board - solid areas of copper interrupted only where vias or connector pins pierce through to reach another layer.

And you'll find that most chips have equal number of power and ground pins/balls, except in some types of packages which have a large solid pad contact; in that case it may be an additional ground, or in a few examples be the only ground.

> Does the voltage regulator up convert ground somehow so that 100 amps doesn't go back through the mains circuit?

Indeed, that is what a *power converter* is meant to do - it takes in power in the form of a higher voltage and lower current, and on the output side it produces a lower voltage at a potentially far higher current.  Even in a design where there is a continuous path of ground between the input and output sides (some converters have that, some don't, some even have the positive side in common), the current on the low voltage side should mostly return to the power converter.

In understanding that, it's important to realize that currently (mostly) takes the path of least resistance.  Even if you provide a large power plane, most of the current will flow on the shortest path.  And to minimize radiated interference, you try to keep the power and ground paths as close to each other as possible - ideally the high currents follow exactly the same path through two planes on different layers of the board.

Further, the highest peak currents from switching transients shouldn't even flow through the power planes at all, rather, they are locally supplied from the bypass capacitors which are supposed to be placed right at each pair of power and ground pins/balls.  **The computer actually runs on the bypass capitors**; the job of the power supply is just to keep them charged up in between the switching transients.

Comment: Worth nothing that there's also typically a couple of stages of conversion in a PC - the PSU reduces the AC line voltage to usually 5V and 12V rails, and then there's a local regulator right next to the CPU on the board that steps down to the core voltage, so that the highest currents are only between that regulator and the CPU. Also in a PC the power consumed is split between several loads, the CPU and GPU are often the two largest, with fans and hard drives consuming most of the remainder, so a figure of 30-50W is about the highest the CPU consumes.

Answer (score 0):

One square of 1_ounce/foot^2 copper foil (the default thickness) has 0.000500 ohms resistance.

100 amps thru that is 0.050 volts.

The power is (I * V) = 100 * 0.05 = 5 watts (dissipated in the square of copper).

The lateral thermal resistance (from edge to edge) of that square of foil is ...... 70 degree Centigrade per watt.

At 5 watts, the temperature gradient across that square is

70 * 5 = 350 degree Centigrade.

To handle all these issues, such PCBs use LOTS OF SQUARES of copper foil, in parallel, for lower electrical resistance and for lower thermal resistance.

Draw some sketches, perhaps on quadrille pads. And ponder how the high currents flow, and where the heat is generated, and how the heat can exit.